# My 7 yr old cant stay asleep beyond 5 or 6 hours?

Tags: sleep, primary-schooler, sleep-deprivation

My 7 year old falls asleep straight away at bedtime, which is any time between 7 & 8 pm, but then wakes any time from as early as midnight onwards, then cant go back to sleep ?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Admittedly, I don't have a suggestion right now, but you could significantly improve your question with more details: What have you and your child tried so far, how is your usual routine, how long has this been going on and did you notice any effects on his / her daytime behaviour? Is this a consistent or occasional pattern, does he / she nap during the day? Any major changes in the child's life? Just waking up and feeling awake or waking from bad dreams? Any other symptoms... (You may edit your own question any time, no special reputation required.)

Comment: Have you tried keeping your child awake an hour longer to see if that will help?  Do you have a bedtime ritual?  What have you tried to help your child go back to sleep after waking?

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of options you could try, I'm sure you must have tried some of these already but here goes:

1. Extend the bedtime to 9 p.m.
2. Ensure that she has some physical activity in the evening i.e. tire her out a bit.
3. Does she nap in the afternoon? If so then perhaps reduce the amount of nap time or stop it all together depending on what she's comfortable with.
4. Environmental factors: Is it something in the room that's bothering her? Try changing things up a bit.. different pillows/bed position/night light/comforter/room temperature etc. Try letting her sleep in a different room or a night or two.
5. Lastly if this is a recent occurrence there could be something bothering her which causes her to stay awake. Probe a bit and see if there is something you can help with? A class at school which she dreads, an after school activity she is not looking forward to (if this happens only on some days of the week).